# How to refactor solution verification function for solving simple ordinary differential equations with Dsolve?

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, replacement, refactoring

I have tried different approaches but none would work for me as I am new to both functional programming and Mathematica. At bottom is the code I have.

**How `verifySolution[...]` Works**

After verifying solution of a simple ODE with the operator form of `ReplaceAll[...]` function returns a short list of up to two levels deep of Boolean values. If only equation is given the function returns `{True}`, `{False}`, or `{Indeterminate}`. For equations (equation and initial condition) the function calls an embedded function twice (mimicking very limited recursion) returning `{{True, True}}`, `{{False, False}}`, or `{{Indeterminate, Indeterminate}}`. This is the limit of the function. I have never seen it return a mix of booleans (e.g. `{{True, False}}`) but I suppose that is possible.

In addition all True values are colored Green, False is colored Red, and Indeterminate is colored Yellow. This is coded to immediately alert user of success or failure or unevaluated verification of solution. Of course this function will be used on a broader scope with modules for solving a limited number of ODE's.

**Goal of Refactor**

`verifySolution[...]` ideally should be capable of handling any number of equations or solutions with booleans any number of levels deep. All returned booleans should be colored appropriately. In addition it is strongly encourage to find an iterative or recursive approach where functions calls itself until done.

```
booleanassignedcolors = {true := Green, false := Red, 
   indet := Yellow}(* alert of success or failure *);
verifySolution[eqs_, sol_] := Module[{sty, form, verify, dep},
   sty[i_, col_] := Style[i, col, Bold];
   form[i_] := 
    If[i == True, sty[i, true], sty[i, false], sty[i, indet]];
   verify = eqs /. sol;
   dep = Depth[verify] - 1;
   {If[dep == 1, 
     form[verify[[1]]], {form[verify[[1, 1]]], form[verify[[1, 2]]]}]}
   ];
(* test verifySolution *)
eqn = x'[t] == a; ic = x[0] == 0; eqs = {eqn, ic};
solfn1 = FullSimplify[
  DSolve[eqn, x, t]];(* success returns {True} *)
solfn2 = FullSimplify[
  DSolve[eqs, x, t]];(* success returns {{True,True}} *)
verifySolution[eqn, solfn1] // Print;
verifySolution[eqs, solfn2] // Print;
```

Comment: This question reads as the specifications of work for hire. In my opinion, this question is inappropriate for the site in its current form, so I will vote to close it. I suggest that you attempt to make the necessary modifications yourself and, if you get stuck on a specific issue, write a new question including the code you attempted, the input and its current / incorrect output, and your desired outcome.

Comment: @MarcoB so instead of permitting the community to decide if they want to help you decide they shouldn't? your privileges must make you feel very powerful.

Comment: @JulesManson Thank you for your efforts. I can recommend you to use `booleanassignedcolors = {true := Blue, false := Red, indet := Orange}` since `Green` and `Yellow` impossible to read.

Comment: @AlexTrounev although not shown it is used on a broader scope in a module where background is dark blue.

Comment: @JulesManson So, `booleanassignedcolors` should be compatible with user interface.